# MonoTouch SIGSEGV Error on TableHeader View

Tags: ios, mono, xamarin.ios

After hours on the forums I still can't figure this out.

Scenario:
I have a table view with expandable lists. When user wants to expand the list clicks on the header and the table refreshes with the new counted values.
The table header view is:

```
[MonoTouch.Foundation.Export("tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:")]
public override  UIView GetViewForHeader (UITableView tableView, int section)
{
    float headerHeight= ...;
    UIView headerView = new UIView (new RectangleF ...);

    UIButton button1=new UIButton(new RectangleF (...));

    //set label for button
    UILabel labelTextButton = new UILabel(new RectangleF ...);
    labelTextButton.Text=...;
    labelTextButton.Lines=2;

    button1.AddSubview(labelTextButton);

    button1.TouchUpInside+= (sender, e) =>{

        ...
        tableView.ReloadData();
    };

    headerView.AddSubview (button1);

    return headerView;
}
```

- When running on the simulator it always gives me an error like this on the first run:

```
       Stacktrace:
     at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) 
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
       at XXX.Mobile.IOS.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in ..../Main.cs:17
       at (wrapper runtime-invoke) .runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) 
    Native stacktrace:
    0   XXXXXXXXX                           0x000a4d6c mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 284
    1   XXXXXXXXX                           0x00018668 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 248
    2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x96a028cb _sigtramp + 43
    3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
    4   UIKit                               0x018bf258 -[UIApplication send  Action:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    5   UIKit                               0x01980021 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    6   UIKit                               0x0198057f -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 578
    7   UIKit                               0x0197f6e8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 546
    8   UIKit                               0x01b831d3 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 7407
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x03ee2afe __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x03ee2a3d __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 381
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x03ec07c2 __CFRunLoopRun + 1106
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x03ebff44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x03ebfe1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x04e8a7e3 GSEventRunModal + 88
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x04e8a668 GSEventRun + 104
    16  UIKit                               0x018bbffc UIApplicationMain + 1211
    17  ???                                 0x0eeb24ed 0x0 + 250291437
    18  ???                                 0x0ec26f40 0x0 + 247623488
    19  ???                                 0x0ec26b48 0x0 + 247622472
    20  ???                                 0x0ec26c9e 0x0 + 247622814
    21  XXXXXXXXX                           0x0001ca32 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 722
    22  XXXXXXXXX                           0x00180b0e mono_runtime_invoke + 126
    23  XXXXXXXXX                           0x00184d04 mono_runtime_exec_main + 420
    24  XXXXXXXXX                           0x0018a0f5 mono_runtime_run_main + 725
    25  XXXXXXXXX                           0x0007a0c5 mono_jit_exec + 149
    26  XXXXXXXXX                           0x00218ac4 main + 1988
    27  XXXXXXXXX                           0x000159cd start + 53
    =================================================================
    Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
    a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
    used by your application.
    =================================================================
```

The application exits into Simulator Homepage. If I start again the application from the simulator interface (not from MonoTouch) it works perfectly every time.

- When loading the application to the Device:

It works fine the first run, but time to time (3 times per day) the application hangs on the same way as on simulator, but with a different error.

```
         2013-04-10 16:03:16.838 XXXXXXXXX[2480:907] -[CALayer BridgeSelector]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2101da0
         2013-04-10 16:03:24.294 XXXXXXXXX[2480:907] Unhandled managed exception: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[CALayer BridgeSelector]: unrecognized selector sent to instance  0x2101da0 (MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException)
          at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName,    System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38 
      at XXX.Mobile.IOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in ...../Main.cs:17 
        Stacktrace:
        Native stacktrace:
        0   XXXXXXXXX                        0x007ff711 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 244
        1   XXXXXXXXX                        0x0083b8cd sigabrt_signal_handler + 112
        2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a847e93 _sigtramp + 42
        3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a83e123 pthread_kill + 58
        4   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a87a973 abort + 94
        5   XXXXXXXXX                        0x0089a230 monotouch_throw_monotouch_exception + 0
        6   XXXXXXXXX                        0x007fd0e9 mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 92
        7   XXXXXXXXX                        0x007b55e3 mono_thread_abort + 46
        8   XXXXXXXXX                        0x007ff3e7 mono_handle_exception_internal + 2138
        9   XXXXXXXXX                        0x007ff4b5 mono_handle_exception + 12
        10  XXXXXXXXX                        0x0083ab31 mono_arm_throw_exception + 132
        11  XXXXXXXXX                        0x003ba468 throw_exception + 68
        12  XXXXXXXXX                        0x0089a27c monotouch_exception_handler + 0
        13  XXXXXXXXX                        0x0089a32c objc_skip_type + 0
        14  CoreFoundation                      0x3252557f  + 614
        15  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3a3c9a65  + 128
        16  libc++abi.dylib                     0x39e1607b  + 78
        17  libc++abi.dylib                     0x39e16114  + 19
        18  libc++abi.dylib                     0x39e17599 cxa_current_exception_type + 0
        19  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3a3c99d1 objc_exception_rethrow + 12
        20  CoreFoundation                      0x3246bf21 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 456
        21  CoreFoundation                      0x3246bd49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
        22  GraphicsServices                    0x360202eb GSEventRunModal + 74
        23  UIKit                               0x34381301 UIApplicationMain + 1120
        24  XXXXXXXXX                        0x0013950c wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string_intptr_intptr + 240
        25  XXXXXXXXX                        0x00674f70 XXX_Mobile_IOS_Application_Main_string__ + 152
        26  XXXXXXXXX                        0x00384db0 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 200
        27  XXXXXXXXX                        0x007b7b7f mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1054
        28  XXXXXXXXX                        0x008315ab mono_runtime_invoke + 90
        29  XXXXXXXXX                        0x00834457 mono_runtime_exec_main + 306
        30  XXXXXXXXX                        0x008346ab mono_runtime_run_main + 482
        31  XXXXXXXXX                        0x007d35db mono_jit_exec + 94
        32  XXXXXXXXX                        0x00888584 main + 2220
        33  XXXXXXXXX                        0x000143e4 start + 40
    =================================================================
    Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
    a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
    used by your application.
    =================================================================
```

I don't know if it's a bug with GC on Monotouch or I am doing something wrong. I've read somewhere that the invalid selector sent to instance was solved.
I tried to put breakpoints in the button event handler but it never reaches that point.

Other posts from forum suggested to put variables as global (not a good programming practice), but that didn't work either.

My configuration:

```
    Xamarin Studio
    Version 4.0.3 (build 13)
    Runtime:
        Mono 2.10.12 (mono-2-10/c9b270d)
        GTK 2.24.16
        GTK# (2.12.0.0)
        Package version: 210120000
    Apple Developer Tools
    Xcode 4.6.1 (2067)
    Build 4H512
    Xamarin.Mac
    Xamarin.Mac: Not Installed
    Xamarin.iOS
    Version: 6.2.2.8 (Business Edition)
    Build date: 2013-02-04 17:10:37-0400
    Build Information
    Release ID: 400030013
    Git revision: fae7c2bde0e8d51943fbd6afa22d7d2bb7a1192f
    Build date: 2013-03-21 19:16:39+0000
    Xamarin addins: 906a1edff23bcfd0ab7518463620a8ee506eaea2
    Operating System
    Mac OS X 10.8.3
```

Thank you for your time

Ovidiu

Comment: Update : I see this happens for Simulator only in DEBUGER mode. In the Release mode the simulator works fine every time. I think it's an issue with Monotouch. For the device the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem:

I observed that with the newer versions of Xamarin.IOS the GC is more aggressive.

I tried everything with my code above but nothing worked.

I think the GC does not retain the variables declared inside Table delegates methods. Any button declared there is taken by GC too soon. Maybe it's something wrong with de-queue of table cells.

Anyway I disabled from Project Options the SGEN building option. It's says there it's experimental.

This resolved my issue, I don't know if it's the best solution but I don't have any ideas. It's frustrating not to be able to debug these memory/allocation issues.

I've checked with Instruments the memory allocation with SGen disabled and the memory is not de-allocated as much as before.

I do not mark this as resolved as my solution is a work around. SGen should not work like this.

Best Regards,

Ovidiu

Answer (score 0):

I was just hitting this issue as well and Ovidiu saved me a few hours of debugging; it was a GC issue for me as well.  In case others hit this - I avoided the GC by defining the UIBUtton in the class rather than in the function.

Comment: But how can you do that if you need an instance of UIBUTTON on each table row for example?