# xamarin/mvvmcross UITableView with static content

Tags: uitableview, mvvmcross, xamarin-studio

I've searched around the xamarin tutorials and over the various posts about UITableView in xamarin but I couldn't found whatever about UITableView with static cells.

What I'm trying to achieve is a simple detail screen like twitterific app, but **without Nib or storyboards** (using mvvmcross, storyboards aren't available and Nib files prevent from using static UITableView, at least I couldn't find any way to do it)

Furthermore, after trying differents solutions I've ended up with something like this:

**UITableViewController**

```
public override int NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
{
    return 1;
}

public override int RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, int section)
{
    return 1;
}

public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{

    UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("test");

    if (cell == null)
    {
        cell = new SejourInfoViewPatientCell();
        //cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, "test");
    }

    //cell.TextLabel.Text = "test";

    return cell;
}
```

But now the mvvmcross binding doesn't works. If I take the exact same binding and use it on a non static UITableViewController everything works fine

If someone could point me to a direction I'll be glad

[image: twitterific]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been struggling with the same problem. I was able to get around the binding issue by having my view inherit from `MvxViewController` then in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
 
public override void ViewDidLoad () 
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    UITableView table = new UITableView(); 

    Action<UITableViewCell> initializers = new Action<UITableViewCell>[] {
          (cell) => { 
              this.CreateBinding(cell.TextLabel)
                  .For(c => c.Text)
                  .To(x => x.FirstName)
                  .Apply();
          },
          (cell) => { 
              this.CreateBinding(cell.TextLabel)
                  .For(c => c.Text)
                  .To(x => x.LastName)
                  .Apply();
          }
    };

    StubDataSource source = new StubDataSource(table, initializers);

    table.Source = source;

}
```

**StubDataSource** inherits from **MvxStandardTableViewSource** (though depending on your needs you'll probably want to inherit off    **UITableViewSource** (overriding `GetCell` instead).

```
public class StubDataSource : MvxStandardTableViewSource
{
    private readonly Action<UITablleViewCell>[] _inits; 

    public StubDataSource(
                UITableView tableView, 
                Action<UITablleViewCell>[] inits) 
            : base(tableView)
    {
          _inits = inits;          
    }

    public override int NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
    {
         return 1;
    }

    public override int RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
         return 2;
    }

    protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
    {
        var reuse = base.CreateDefaultBindableCell(tableView, indexPath, item);

        switch(indexPath.Row) 
        {
             case 0:
                _inits[0](reuse);
             case 1:
                _inits[1](reuse);
        }

        return reuse;
    }

}
```

Two points to note,

1. This is a bit of hack (thanks Closures), but its the only way to bind to static tables in ios that I can think of. Hopefully someone will suggest a better way.
2. The second is when you create custom cells with subviews (e.g. UITextFields etc) you should create a custom cell type and have those subviews as a class variable, otherwise the GC will collect them you'll get **SIGSEGV** exceptions [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927019/monotouch-sigsegv-error-on-tableheader-view)

Comment: sorry for late answer, i was on another project. But it works great thanks a lot :)

Comment: No problem, by the way I've since discovered that the monotouch Dialog components provide a good match for many of the prblems I was trying to solve using static tables. Check  out http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/monotouch.dialog/ and https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/DialogExamples/DialogExamples.Touch

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what a `static` TableView or Cell are, but I've just posted a complete sample using "custom cells" on https://github.com/slodge/ListApp in answer to [MvxTableViewSource DequeueReusableCell issue when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688493/mvxtableviewsource-dequeuereusablecell-issue-when-scrolling)

The key parts were:

- ensure the custom cell includes an `IntPtr` constructor
- use `RegisterClassForCellReuse` on the custom cell type
- override `GetOrCreateCellFor` in your table source - and use `DequeueReusableCell` to create the cell

For variable height cells, you'll also need to override `GetHeightForRow` within the table source

Comment: for static, I mean a UITableViewCell with fixed sections and cells (you can do that pretty easily in Xcode >4.2 by changing cell type to "static")